# Can I run non server OS 10.6.8 using VMware?

Tags: macos, snow-leopard, virtualization

Two part question really:

1) can it be done at all (standard version NOT server)?

2) if it can be done can I import an existing standard 10.6.8 system from an external disk with VMWare or do I have to clean install and use OSX's native Migration Assistant?

My plan is to upgrade my MBP (mid 2010 with i7 processor) to Mavericks and run my old 10.6.8 system virtually. I can buy VMWare Fusion 7 (the latest version).

Comment: Technically? Yes. Legally? No.

Answer (score 1):

No.  The End User License Agreement for 10.6 does not allow for virtualization unless you have purchased the Server version.  VMware Fusion (as well as VMware ESXi and VMware Workstation) honors the EULA and does not allow virtualization if the OS X EULA does not allow it.

Answer (score 0):

On the question of "Can it be done"? The answer is yes.
There is an Apple script to manipulate the mounted image:

```
do shell script "if [ -a /Volumes/'Mac OS X Install DVD'* ]; then { vol=(/Volumes/'Mac OS X Install DVD'*); mountrw='while true; do /sbin/mount -u -o rw / && break; sleep 1; done; '; mountro='; while true; do /sbin/mount -u -o ro / && break; sleep 1; done; touch /tmp/test_ro 2>/dev/null && rm /tmp/test_ro 2>/dev/null && shutdown -r now'; }; else { unset mountrw; unset mountro; while read thisVol; do grep -q '10.6' /Volumes/\"$thisVol\"/System/Library/CoreServices/SystemVersion.plist 2>/dev/null && vol=/Volumes/\"$thisVol\" && break; done <<< \"$(ls -1 /Volumes)\"; }; fi; if [ -a \"$vol\" ]; then { cd \"$vol\"; echo \"$mountrw\"'/bin/rm /System/Library/CoreServices/ServerVersion.plist'\"$mountro\" > etc/rc.local; echo \"$mountrw\"'/bin/cp /System/Library/CoreServices/SystemVersion.plist /System/Library/CoreServices/ServerVersion.plist' > etc/rc.shutdown.local; cd System/Library/CoreServices; cp SystemVersion.plist ServerVersion.plist; echo done; }; else echo 'Snow Leopard volume not found'; fi" with administrator privileges
```